# How do I resolve a SSH admin user command for a bitbucket installation on the QNAP?

Tags: qnap, bitbucket.org, elasticsearch

I’m attempting to install Atlassian’s BitBucket on my [QNAP 453](https://www.qnap.com/en-us/product/model.php?II=149) with little success. I’ve downloaded the `.bin` file from Atlassian, paid for a subscription, and am now trying to install on my QNAP via SSH. The problem is that I can only SSH into my QNAP as an admin and I’m experiencing an error that states I should only run theElasticsearch command as a non-admin account.

How do I either SSH into my QNAP as a non-admin so that I can run the Elasticsearch command, or is there an alternative method to installing BitBucket on the QNAP?

**Error Message:**

```
If you cannot access Bitbucket within 3 minutes, or encounter other issues, check the troubleshooting guide at:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BitbucketServerKB/Troubleshooting+Installation
[admin@QNAP bin]# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: don't run elasticsearch as root.
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
```

Comment: QNAP only allows admin via SSH.

Comment: Agree with @JakeGould: I don't own a QNAP so I can't check myself, but why do you you say you can only ssh as admin? This doesn't sound right, you should be able to have a number of users, both privileged and unprivileged, and allow ssh with any of them.

Comment: The actual admin panel says that only admin works for SSH for security purposes. I created new users but SSH doesn't work for them.

Comment: You might work around this limitation by ssh'ing as admin and subsequently `su` to another user in order to run the command that requires a non-privileged user.

Comment: I tried running "su" but it says command not found. [~/.ssh] # su
-sh: su: command not found [~/.ssh] # uname -a
Linux QNAP 3.19.8 #1 SMP Thu Apr 13 05:21:58 CST 2017 x86_64 unknown BusyBox v1.01 (2017.04.12-17:45+0000) multi-call binary

Comment: Turns out they have a custom command to change users.